# Unable to access Bundle in swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get some info from a plist but when I try to access bundle in a swift file I am not able to access it. When I type bundle, Xcode is not recommending anything. It works on other swift files in the same project. I don't know what can be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Bundle` is a [*Foundation*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) class, ensure you are importing the *Foundation* framework at the beginning of your Swift file.

> **Note:** *UIKit* includes the *Foundation* framework, so you can alternatively `import UIKit`.

```swift
import Foundation
```

This should enable SourceKit’s—& therefore Xcode’s—code completion.

Answer (score 0):

It's may a bug of Xcode about code suggestion.
You can access `Bundle.main` normally without any problem.

Restart Xcode may solve code suggestion problem.

UPDATE:
If your file not import Foundation or UIKit, You must import Foundation to access Bundle